# Accessing validator’s state inside a template for an control in a FormArray

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation

I am using Angular’s reactive forms and would like to apply a css style to controls inside a FormArray depending on the value of the control’s invalid property.  I have come up with the following approach but I think the expression inside the ngClass property is too long and complex.  Is there a more succinct way to access the invalid property for a control within a FormArray?

Template:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error': myForm.controls.name.invalid }">
        <label class="control-label">Name</label>
        <input formControlName="name" type="text" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div formArrayName="array1">
        <div *ngFor="let f of array1_FA.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
            <div>
                <div class="form-group" 
                    [ngClass]="{'has-error': myForm.controls.array1.at(i).controls.question.invalid}">

                    <label class="control-label">Question #{{i+1}}</label>
                    <input formControlName="question" class="form-control" type="text" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" 
                    [ngClass]="{'has-error': myForm.controls.array1.at(i).controls.response.invalid}">

                    <label class="control-label">Answer #{{i+1}}</label>
                    <input formControlName="response" class="form-control" type="text" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'form-array-validation',
    templateUrl: './form-array-validation.component.html'
})

export class FormArrayValidationComponent {

    myForm: FormGroup;
    questions = ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'];

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.createForm();
    }

    createForm() {
        this.myForm = this.fb.group({
            name: ['Name1', Validators.required],
            array1: this.fb.array(this.questions.map(val => this.fb.group({
                question: [val, Validators.required],
                response: [null, Validators.required]
            })))
        });
    }

    get array1_FA(): FormArray {
        return this.myForm.get('array1') as FormArray;
    };
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at .get? That provides a shortcut syntax: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#inspect-formcontrol-properties

Comment: I do think .get makes it more readable but still very close. `myForm.get('array1').at(i).get('question').invalid`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case you can make use of your `f` in the iteration in template:

```html
*ngFor="let f of array1_FA.controls;
```

which makes your code a bit shorter/cleaner, so instead of:

```html
[ngClass]="{'has-error': myForm.controls.array1.at(i).controls.question.invalid}">
```

do:

```html
[ngClass]="{'has-error': f.get('question').invalid}
```

or

```html
[ngClass]="{'has-error': f.controls.question.invalid}
```

Comment: Perfect!  I was just reminded of Angular class binding and am using: `[class.has-error]="f.get('question').invalid"`

Comment: sure thing, I didn't look even at the class implementation, just looked at the "shortening" of the property paths, ignoring the rest :D But yes, that is a wise move :)

Answer (score 1):

When a form group is not valid, Angular add the ng-invalid class on it. You can use this to entirely remove the class binding.

Comment: In this particular instance I am trying to use some existing css classes from a third party framework.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
myForm.get(`array1.${i}.question`).invalid
```

Note that these are back ticks.

(I had to change it to an answer because the comments were eating the back ticks.)

Comment: This is an interesting idea but I don't think I can use the backticks inside an template, at least I have not been able to make this work.